# Cross domain for different protocols

Tags: ajax, protocols, same-origin-policy

Edit: found answer here [Ajax using https on an http page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105934/ajax-http-https-problem)

How can I bypass same origin policy for different protocols?

I found this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

It says http and https is not the same domain. Is possible cross-sub-domain method like

document.domain = "https://company.com";

on the caller document?

Of course given that both sites are in company.com. The difference is one uses http and the other https.

Or do I have to use the usual cross domain methods like JSONP, proxy and CORS?