# constraints in accessing a ssl enabled wcf rest service from jquery

Tags: jquery, rest

I have a wcf rest service. I want to know what are the constraints involved or rather the plumbings required in accessing the service from jquery using $.ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

If you consume the SSL services from a non-SSL client, then users may run into browser security issues since this then becomes a cross domain security issue. There are many resources online if you search for cross domain ajax requests. [Ajax using https on an http page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105934/ajax-http-https-problem) is one such resource with some suggested approaches for working around the issue.

If you are consuming the SSL WCF rest services from a client that is also running under the same SSL domain, there shouldn't be anything unique that is required for you to get it to work.