# ajax request not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, firebug

I am implementing a web application. I'm trying to send huge data from client side to server side by using js Ajax with POST method.

In the Ajax, I set the parameter, which is a big string containing over 30000 characters. It works fine both in IE9 and Chrome. But not work in Firefox.

Then I made a test, if I send the data length beyond about 6218 then FF wont work. I tried to add one more word in the parameter, then it did not work. It seems to be the data length issue.

But I tried o reproduce it in my local, I sent over 70000 characters, but FF WORKS! 
So right now, I do not what I should do and what the problem exactly is. Please help me.

Comment: This does not solve your problem. But are you setting the parameter in the URL or putting it in the POST body?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I put the param in the POST, not url. If this cannot solve the issue, what should I do?

Comment: Setup a http://jsfiddle.net/ and reproduce the error?

Comment: Exactly same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148483/ajax-post-being-aborted-by-firefox-not-seen-in-chrome-or-ie    But still there is no explicit solution.

Comment: Did you get a solution? BTW, in your link there is a comment about `setTimeout` did you tried that? You are doing multiple requests "at the same time"?

Comment: The thing is I cannot reproduce the issue in local (it happens on production level), so I cannot make the code change....