# Ajax GET request never succeeds

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a 'simple' GET request that pulls the content of a webpage back so that I can use data within the webpage at a later stage.

For some reason my code never enters the success function and I don't understand why the get request is always failing.

Hoping someone can notice something I haven't, or maybe I am just using the wrong approach?

Thanks in advance, here is my code:

```
$(function() {
$(".button").click(function() {
// validate and process form here
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.mycarcheck.com/check/?reg_no=",
        dataType: "html",
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(URL);
            alert(data);
        }
   });
});
});
```

Comment: Is `mycarcheck.com` the same domain as the site is being viewed on? If not, you are falling foul of the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Have you tried adding an Error section to see what the message is?

Comment: What does the JavaScript error console say?

Comment: I added an error will following alerts: alert(xhr.status) and alert(thrownError).

Comment: They display 0 and No transport!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have either 1 or 2 problems:

#### HTTPS via HTTP

http://www.mycarcheck.com/check/?reg_no= redirects (via 301) to https://www.mycarcheck.com/check/?reg_no= (httpS).

You can't communicate with a secure server from a non secure one, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105934/ajax-using-https-on-an-http-page).

If you load your page under HTTPS then the request should work.

#### Same Origin Policy

If your website is not on the same domain as mycarcheck.com, your AJAX request is in violation of the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

*If* you are in violation then you may still be able to complete the request in modern browsers with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). In this case the server at mycarcheck.com would be able to allow the request, but only if it wants to.

Comment: Ah I see! I have modified the URL to https but this hasn't fixed it. Looking into the same origin policy now to see if I can fix it that way!