# Implementing material design icons for iOS and mobile Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, material-design

I'm using some material icons in a web project.

Now the Google documentation states that the icon font for the web works specifically on **retina** displays (which by my understanding refers to Apple devices):

https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web

> Supported by all modern web browsers.
>
> Vector-based: Looks great at any scale, retina displays, low-dpi
>   display screens.

However it goes on to state:

> The icon font contains 750+ icons and weighs in at only 40KB (woff2
>   format). In comparison, a ZIP file of these in SVGs will be more than
>   50% larger.

I am currently using the self hosted version of the icon font which only refers to the woff2 format and declares the font like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v8/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

I then call the icons with ligatures:

```
<i class="material-icons">face</i>
```

Now when the [documentation](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web) and my web project are viewed using mobile Safari on iOS devices such as iPhone and iPad they do not display at all (the icons that do display are a different icon font):

Is there a way to resolve this issue? Does the .svg format need including for example?

Comment: Is your website itself a https site?

Comment: No. Does that create a potential issue?

Comment: It could; loading mixed content is frowned upon. Is it possible to load the font through http rather than https?

Comment: What an interesting fix. They now display on iOS. This has resolved the issue and can be submitted as an answer possibly? May I ask do you have any reputable resources that discuss mixed content conflicts/issues and why it is bad practice?

Comment: I can't seem to find any official documents; only about problemns in the other direction (loading http resources in a https page). [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1105934/1016716) may provide some insight, but I think I'll leave the actual answering here to someone who can provide a real authoritative answer.