# How to redirect https to http (no SSL certificate)

Tags: apache, http, ssl, redirect, https

Let's imagine a hypothetical situation.

**Site A** is linking to **site B** using **https://** protocol, but site B does not have a SSL certificate.

What can site B do to ensure it still receives visitors from site A?

Comment: Can't use https without certificate. So either get one or use http. Otherwise linking to https version of website wouldn't work - if you have a cert. and https works, there's nothing you need to do in order to link between them with regular `<a>` tags, but you can't load AJAX between the domains unless they're both using the same scheme or they have the correct access control headers

Comment: What if you are the owner of site B and you don't have control over site A, but you still want to receive that traffic without installing SSL?

Comment: Are you trying to simply redirect/link or use AJAX to fetch or send information? If it's the former, you can always link/redirect to whatever you want, as there is no direct connection between A and B. If you need AJAX, try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105934/ajax-using-https-on-an-http-page)

Comment: It's worth noting that in 2017 there're several places where you can get a certificate for free, if that's the issue.